# Python: How to remove empty lists from a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list with empty lists in it:

```
list1 = [[], [], [], [], [], 'text', 'text2', [], 'moreText']
```

How can I remove the empty lists so that I get:

```
list2 = ['text', 'text2', 'moreText']
```

I tried list.remove('') but that doesn't work.

Comment: `'' != []`, that's why `.remove` didn't work. But it's still a bad solution (either you check if there is `[] in list1` before hand - `O(n**2)` - or catch the error it throws otherwise - ugly).

Comment: so amazing when u found that although your question is not common, but someone long ago has posted it and it has been beautifully answered! I love SO

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Try

```
list2 = [x for x in list1 if x != []]
```

If you want to get rid of everything that is "falsy", e.g. empty strings, empty tuples, zeros, you could also use

```
list2 = [x for x in list1 if x]
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the other way that springs to mind and how it differs.

Comment: I know this is old, but I keep seeing that brace method and I can't find anything via Google on it (Probably because Google doesn't do punctuation). What is that called so I can learn more about what is really happening there?

Comment: @David: [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [Generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).  There are also dictionary comprehensions and set comprehensions.

Answer (score 91):

You can use `filter()` instead of a list comprehension:

```
list2 = filter(None, list1)
```

If `None` is used as first argument to `filter()`, it filters out every value in the given list, which is `False` in a boolean context.  This includes empty lists.

It might be slightly faster than the list comprehension, because it only executes a single function in Python, the rest is done in C.

Comment: why doesn't this answer have more upvotes and / or be the accepted answer?

Comment: @MattO'Brien b/c many Python programmers avoid `filter()`, as wells as `lambda`, `map()`, and `reduce()`; this includes [Guido himself](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196), although that post is a bit old. I tend to prefer list comprehensions b/c the clarity is often more important than the slight speedup with these methods and the `lambda` operator. That being said, this case is trivial b/c it's very clear what the programmer's intent is.

Comment: In Python3 I think this has to be amended to: list2 = list(filter(None, list1)). Just in case any newbies using Python3 wonder why this doesn't work for them :)

Comment: @Shaken_not_stirred. yaaaas. I am a newbie and I love SO. This response helped me avoid hours of hair-tearing!

Answer (score 10):

Calling `filter` with `None` will filter out all falsey values from the list (which an empty list is)

```
list2 = filter(None, list1)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> list1 = [[], [], [], [], [], 'text', 'text2', [], 'moreText']
>>> list2 = [e for e in list1 if e]
>>> list2
['text', 'text2', 'moreText']
```

Comment: Can someone please edit this! I can't seem to get the formatting options.

Comment: done (you need to use the `{}`)

Comment: @RC: Thanks! I know that, but for some weird reason it is not visible (no option is).

Answer (score 4):

A few options:

```
filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, list1)  # Doesn't work with number types
filter(None, list1)  # Filters out int(0)
filter(lambda x: x==0 or x, list1) # Retains int(0)
```

sample session:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 17:19:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> list1 = [[], [], [], [], [], 'text', 'text2', [], 'moreText']
>>> filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, list1)
['text', 'text2', 'moreText']
>>> list2 = [[], [], [], [], [], 'text', 'text2', [], 'moreText', 0.5, 1, -1, 0]
>>> filter(lambda x: x==0 or x, list2)
['text', 'text2', 'moreText', 0.5, 1, -1, 0]
>>> filter(None, list2)
['text', 'text2', 'moreText', 0.5, 1, -1]
>>>
```

Comment: -1:  `len(x) > 0` is essentially the same as `bool(x)` or just `x`.

Comment: +1: @RC. If you have number types in your list, you can't call len on it. If you have a `0`, it will be filtered out by `None`. Otherwise I like this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question because I wanted to do the same as the OP.
I would like to add the following observation:

The iterative way (user225312, Sven Marnach):

```
list2 = [x for x in list1 if x]
```

Will return a `list` object in `python3` and `python2` . Instead the filter way (lunaryorn, Imran) will differently behave over versions:

```
list2 = filter(None, list1)
```

It will return a `filter` object in `python3` and a `list` in `python2` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12319025/3067485) found at the same time). This is a slight difference but it must be take in account when developing compatible scripts.

This does not make any assumption about performances of those solutions. Anyway the filter object can be reverted to a list using:

```
list3 = list(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1,'aa',3,12,'a','b','c','s'],[],[],[1,'aa',7,80,'d','g','f',''],[9,None,11,12,13,14,15,'k']]

b=[]
for lng in range(len(a)):
       if(len(a[lng])>=1):b.append(a[lng])
a=b
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1,'aa',3,12,'a','b','c','s'],[1,'aa',7,80,'d','g','f',''],[9,None,11,12,13,14,15,'k']]
```

Comment: You posted this in 2015; it has got zero points until it solved my problem in 2021. Lesson: keep rendering help. You do not know who your solution gets to benefit the most! Thanks. Plus one.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [[], [], [], [], [], 'text', 'text2', [], 'moreText']
list2 = []
for item in list1:
    if item!=[]:
        list2.append(item)
print(list2)
```

output:

```
['text', 'text2', 'moreText']
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very useful on their own. It would help if you could add some detail explaining how/why it answers the question. That said, I'm not sure this answer adds any value over all the others to this five-year old question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers above, Say you have a `list of lists` of the form:

```
theList = [['a','b',' '],[''],[''],['d','e','f','g'],['']]
```

and you want to take out the empty entries from each list as well as the empty lists you can do:

```
theList = [x for x in theList if x != ['']] #remove empty lists
for i in range(len(theList)):
    theList[i] = list(filter(None, theList[i])) #remove empty entries from the lists
```

Your new list will look like

```
theList = [['a','b'],['d','e','f','g']]
```