# Failure when filtering string list with re.match

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to filter a list of strings in python by using regex. In the following case, keeping only the files with a '.npy' extension.

The code that doesn't work:

```
import re

files = [ '/a/b/c/la_seg_x005_y003.png',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x005_y003.npy',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x004_y003.png',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x004_y003.npy',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x003_y003.png',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x003_y003.npy', ]

regex = re.compile(r'_x\d+_y\d+\.npy')

selected_files = filter(regex.match, files)
print(selected_files)
```

The same regex works for me in Ruby:

```
selected = files.select { |f| f =~ /_x\d+_y\d+\.npy/ }
```

What's wrong with the Python code?

Comment: You wan to filter the elements in `files` with the `.npy` extension?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
selected_files = filter(regex.match, files)
```

[`re.match('regex')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) equals to `re.search('^regex')` or `text.startswith('regex')` but regex version. **It only checks if the string starts with the regex**.

So, use `re.search()` instead:

```
import re

files = [ '/a/b/c/la_seg_x005_y003.png',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x005_y003.npy',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x004_y003.png',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x004_y003.npy',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x003_y003.png',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x003_y003.npy', ]

regex = re.compile(r'_x\d+_y\d+\.npy')

selected_files = list(filter(regex.search, files))
# The list call is only required in Python 3, since filter was changed to return a generator
print(selected_files)
```

Output:

```
['/a/b/c/la_seg_x005_y003.npy',
 '/a/b/c/la_seg_x004_y003.npy',
 '/a/b/c/la_seg_x003_y003.npy']
```

---

And if you just want to get all of the `.npy` files, [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) would be a better choice:

```
files = [ '/a/b/c/la_seg_x005_y003.png',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x005_y003.npy',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x004_y003.png',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x004_y003.npy',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x003_y003.png',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x003_y003.npy', ]


selected_files = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.npy'), files))

print(selected_files)
```

Comment: I wondered why `filter()` accepts the the `re.search()`-method, as the latter returns an instance of `MatchObject` and not a boolean. It is explained [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/functional_programming/filtering_lists.html) in 16.8.3: The `search()`-method returns a MatchObject if the item matches and `filter()` interprets that as True. Otherwise `search()` returns None, which is interpreted as False.

Comment: In Python 3.x, `filter()` [returns a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12319034/2573061), so you need to wrap it in `list()` if that's what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `search`- since match starts matching from the beginning to end (i.e. entire) of string and search matches anywhere in the string.

```
import re

files = [ '/a/b/c/la_seg_x005_y003.png',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x005_y003.npy',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x004_y003.png',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x004_y003.npy',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x003_y003.png',
          '/a/b/c/la_seg_x003_y003.npy', ]

regex = re.compile(r'_x\d+_y\d+\.npy')

selected_files = filter(regex.search, files)
print(selected_files)
```

Output-

```
['/a/b/c/la_seg_x005_y003.npy', '/a/b/c/la_seg_x004_y003.npy', '/a/b/c/la_seg_x003_y003.npy']
```

Answer (score 3):

[`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) looks for a match at the beginning of the string. You can use `re.search()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you [match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match), the pattern must cover the *entire* input.
Either extend you regular expression:

```
regex = re.compile(r'.*_x\d+_y\d+\.npy')
```

Which would match:

```
['/a/b/c/la_seg_x005_y003.npy',
 '/a/b/c/la_seg_x004_y003.npy',
 '/a/b/c/la_seg_x003_y003.npy']
```

Or use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), which

> scans through string looking for the *first location* where the regular expression pattern produces a match [...]