# Transformation of file list based on higher priority

Tags: python, priority-queue

I have a list of files in a directory with different names, I need to transform all the files one at a time based on priority.Files starting with 'AB' to have higher priority over the ones with 'CD'. Within each of those set order the file by Name ascending and pick the first one.

Input :
AB_2908_02P.xml
CD_2908_02P.xml

Code:

```
def Send_Request(self):
    Directory = "c://users/request/"
    #Type = 'AB','CD'
    xml_files = Type + '_' + '2908_02P' + '.xml'
    if os.path.exists(Directory+xml_files):
        for file in os.listdir(Directory):
            #AB_2908_02P.xml
            #CD_2908_02P.xml
            if file.startswith('AB'):
                print ("first priority")
            elif file.startswith('CD'):
                print("second priority")
```

Can anyone please let me know what is the best way to use a priority queue?

Comment: Please provide a more through example of input and output, I don't understand exactly what the specification of this problem is.

Comment: Why do you think a priority queue is a good idea for this? If you think it's a good idea, read the docs on `heapq`

Comment: Welcome! can you get the full list at one time and set priorities without risk of new files coming in during the process? If so, the just make two empty lists, loop filenames and append them to the corresponding list, sort the lists and concatenate them

Comment: ...since _AB_ has higher priority than _CD_, why not just sort the list of all files according to the lexicographical order of their names? e.g. ```for file in sorted(os.listdir(Directory))```. this will automatically iterate over _AB_ files first...

Comment: @mrxra That is just an example I have mentioned

Comment: @Richie Nope its a scheduled job and will be running on every 5 mins and it will generate a different set of files every time.

Comment: @Gulzar Input I have provided above. Actual scenario is In a particular directory we have a list of files ex:(AB_2908_02P.xml, CD_2908_02P.xml). In a loop I'm trying to process one file at a time and picking of file has to happen based on the prefix(i.e AB). If and file starts with 'AB' it has to run first and later check for 'CD' type. But how to prioritize files in loop based on the prefix is my question

Comment: @MadPhysicist In heapq I have seen example for prioritizing the integer but not string. Can you please give me an example if you have or link may help

Comment: I think 5 minutes is enough to count as static in terms of priority changes. Try making the two lists and using `sorted(list)` on each one

Comment: Or build the lists with regex https://stackoverflow.com/q/34117950/6692898

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could take advantage of python's native capability to sort tuples. create a lookup table `prio` for your prefixes, then sort the list of files using a sort key: the function generates a tuple (prio, filename) for each file as sorting criteria:

```
import math

files = [
    "AB_2908_02P.xml",
    "CD_2908_02P.xml",
    "AB_2909_02P.xml",
    "CD_2910_02P.xml",
    "XY_2908_03P.xml",
    "CD_3008_02P.xml",
    "AC_xxxx_yyy_zzzzz.xml"
]

prio = {
    'AB': 5,
    'CD': 0,
    'XY': 3
}

for filename in sorted(files, key=lambda f: (prio.get(f.partition('_')[0], math.inf), f)):
    print(filename)
```

prints:

```
CD_2908_02P.xml
CD_2910_02P.xml
CD_3008_02P.xml
XY_2908_03P.xml
AB_2908_02P.xml
AB_2909_02P.xml
AC_xxxx_yyy_zzzzz.xml
```

NOTE: the code uses *math.inf* as default priority in case no prio is defined for a certain prefix (as is the case with *AC* in the example above).

Comment: Thanks it worked. But still I have one doubt here,in for loop it sorts based on the priority and lists all the files from the directory.Suppose once loop starts if any other priority file comes(ex: AB) in between how to execute that over the other files?

Comment: ...what exactly do you mean by _Suppose once loop starts if any other priority file comes(ex: AB) in between_? come in between how exactly?

Comment: When for loop starts all the files in a directory are listed and sorted based on the prio condition and will execute one after the another. But after loop starts,if I add some more files into that directory with a high priority files then how to include the latest updated files also into the same loop?

Comment: ...you'd probably have to have at least 2 threads, one observing the filesystem for changes, one processing the files....with the former one interrupting the latter in case new files appear. this is _not_ trivial to do right (you need to track files, make sure your data structures are thread safe, handle cases where you process unexpectedly dies, etc). also, you'd still inspect the filesystem at _discrete_ moments in time (with files dis-/appearing in between). I don't understand your _exact_ requirements, please be more specific