# Filter object has no attribute pop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
colorramps = re.split("#ramp\[([0-9a-fA-F]{6})\](.+?)#rampend\[([0-9a-fA-F]{6})\]", message)
colorramps.reverse()
if len(colorramps) > 1:
    starttext = colorramps.pop()
    starttext = starttext.replace("$message", getSaveString(text))
    starttext = starttext.replace("$playername", getSaveString(username), 1)
    complete = [starttext]
    while len(colorramps):
        startcolor = getColor(colorramps.pop())
        colors = filter(None, re.split("#over\[([0-9a-fA-F]{6})\]", colorramps.pop()))
        middletxt = colors.pop()
        endcolor = getColor(colorramps.pop())
        middletxt = middletxt.replace("$message", getSaveString(text))
        middletxt = middletxt.replace("$playername", getSaveString(username), 1)
        middletxt = middletxt.decode("utf")
        if len(colors) > 0:
            colors = map(getColor, colors)
            colors.append(endcolor)
            middletxt = rangeOverColors(middletxt, startcolor, colors)
        else:
            middletxt = getRangeString(middletxt, startcolor, endcolor)
        middletxt = middletxt.encode("utf")
        complete.append(middletxt)
        endtext = colorramps.pop()
        endtext = endtext.replace("$message", getSaveString(text))
        endtext = endtext.replace("$playername", getSaveString(username), 1)
        complete.append(endtext)
    message = "".join(complete)
else:
    message = message.replace("$message", getSaveString(text))
    message = message.replace("$playername", getSaveString(username), 1)
return message
```

Hello guys!
Im getting in line 128, in replaceColorRamps
    middletxt = colors.pop()

AttributeError: 'filter' object has no attribute 'pop'

I used this code for python 2.5 and now im porting it to 3.4..

Can someone help me

Comment: You should create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't know what "line 128" is in your code and this doesn't look like anyone can run it locally to reproduce.

Answer (score 12):

Are you running this in Python 3?

In Python 2.7 `filter()` returned a `list`, which has `.pop()` function.
In Python 3.x `filter()` returns a `filter` iterable object which does not.

Before you can `.pop()` from the `filter` in Python 3 you need to convert it to a list. So add e.g.

```
colors = list(colors)
```

after the `colors = filter(...)` line. In Python 2.7 this will have no effect, so your code will continue to work there. See [this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12319034/754456)  and [these docs](http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#filter).

Comment: Thanks mfitzp. That's what I wanted to know.