# Python Class and List Filters

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, filter

To get to the point I'm learning how to work classes and list comprehension and I'm running into this problem:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

def are_in_first_quadrant(listPoint):
    newListPoint = filter(lambda pnt: pnt.x > 0 and pnt.y > 0, listPoint)
    return newListPoint

pList = [Point(-3,7), Point(2,3), Point(7,0), Point(6,-9), Point(7,9)]
    newList = are_in_first_quadrant(pList)
```

So you can see the goal of this is to spew out a list of points that are in the first quadrant, but when I try to print 'newList' I get:

```
[<objects.Point instance at 0x0293FA08>, <objects.Point instance at 0x0293FA80>]
```

Instead of:

```
[Point(2,3) , Point(7.9)]
```

Looking over this post: [Filters in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319025/filters-in-python)
I understand the print out is the memory location but I don't really gain much more from that.

So question is how exactly do I fix this?
I'm guessing it probably has to do with how I used lambda but again not too sure.
I'm using Python 2.7

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Also just tried

```
def are_in_first_quadrant(listPoint):
    newListPoint = [pnt for pnt in listPoint if pnt.x > 0 and pnt.y > 0]
    return newListPoint
```

and it throws up the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a [`__repr__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) for your `Point` class:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)
```

This method will be called for each element when the list is printed.

Just a remark: a function called `are_...` (or `is_...`) is supposed to return `True` or `False`. A more suitable name would be `points_in_first_quadrant()`.

For a comparison between `__str__()` and `__repr__()`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python).

Comment: An alternative that's useful if you want your points to be immutable is `Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', 'x y')`. This provides the init and repr for you.

Comment: Thanks, I saw your edit earlier when you said to use a __str__() method as opposed to a __repr__() method, for future reference could you explain how to know which one to use?

Comment: No need to explain this by myself, there's a Q for this alreadyl