# Checking a variable against a list and seeing if a word in that list starts with the variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that uses a checker that could be any length and checks it against the list. It should be case insensitive when checking and print the word. Example below

`Input= startsWith('a',['apple','ApPle','orange','Apple','kiwi','apricot'])`

**Output:**

```
apple
ApPle 
Apple 
apricot
```

But, it prints every string in the list all in lower case.

```
def startsWith(checker,lister):

    checker.lower()
    size = len(lister)
    i=0
    checklength = len(checker)
    lister = [element.lower() for element in lister]
    while(i<size):
        checkinlist = lister[i]
        if(checkinlist[0:checklength-1] in checker):
            # this is just to test to see if the variables are what i need
            # once the if statement works just append them to a new list
            # and print that
            print(lister[i])

        i=i+1
```

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'checker' is not defined`, when I run your script.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen thats because you didn't include the function definition, which is not properly formatted in the question at the moment.

Comment: ...and is now fixed.

Comment: Although it is now formatted correctly, what is your actual question?

Comment: lister contains only lowercase strings when you print it. What are you confused about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def startsWith(checker,lister):

    for i in range(len(lister)):
        words = lister[i].lower()
        if(words.startswith(checker)):
            print(lister[i])

def main():
    startsWith('a',['apple','ApPle','orange','Apple','kiwi','apricot'])
main()
```

OUTPUT

```
apple
ApPle
Apple
apricot
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the root of the problem

```
lister = [element.lower() for element in lister]
```

`lister` now only contains lowercase strings, which you then print. You need to delay the `lower()` until you check for `checker`.

---

No need to check the length of anything. You can use [`filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319025/filters-in-python#12319034)

```
def startsWith(checker, lister):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x.lower().startswith(checker.lower()), lister))

for x in startsWith('a',['apple','ApPle','orange','Apple','kiwi','apricot']):
    print(x)
```

Output

```
apple
ApPle
Apple
apricot
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not mutate the original elements of `lister`, rather do the comparison on a new copy of those elements that has been converted to lower case.

It can be done in a single list comprehension.

```
def startsWith(checker, lister):
    cl = checker.lower()
    return [s for s in lister if s.lower().startswith(cl)]

Input= startsWith('a',['apple','ApPle','orange','Apple','kiwi','apricot'])

for i in Input:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
apple
ApPle
Apple
apricot
```