# Python: list(filter object) empties the object

Tags: python, list, filter, python-3.6

guys!

I'm using Python 3.6.1 and got into an interesting issue:
I'm using a simple itertools.filter() to get a sub-list from an `items` list, and then I just print it twice.

```
items = [1,2,3,4,5]
operateVersions = filter(lambda t: t, items)
print ("1: %s" % list(operateVersions))
print ("2: %s" % list(operateVersions))
```

The result is weird:

```
1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2: []
```

so, when i run `list(operateVersions)` it somehow rewrites `operateVersions` filter object instead of just returning the list interpretation
Is it an OK behavior? It doesn't look for me it is

Comment: Are you using `itertools.filter`?  As far as I'm aware, it doesn't exist in python3.x (at least, it doesn't exist on python3.5  which is what is installed on my machine).

Comment: Very related:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/12319025/748858 -- specifically, if you want to iterate over the iterator multiple times, you need to store the list in `operateVersions` rather than the iterator.

Comment: @mgilson or in this case directly apply the filter to `items` each time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A filter is a special iterable object, and like a generator, you can only iterate over it once. So essentially it returns an empty list when you run it a second time.