# How to obtain elements of a filter object into a list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter

```
myList = list(range(1,50))

# subsetting just the odd ones
neighbors = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, myList)
print(list(neighbors))
```

the output I'm getting is: "[ ]"

I want to store the elements of "neighbors" in a list so i can use that as an argument for the x_axis for my plot?
how can i do this?

Comment: `neighbors = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, myList))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filters in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319025/filters-in-python3)

Comment: It worked just perfect, Thanks!

Comment: Or just `[x for x in myList if x % 2 != 0]`.