# Python remove empty elements from list of lists

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of lists like this:

```
[['A001', 'atendimento', 'sust', 'concessionário', 'adv', 'bom', 'adj', '', ''],
 ['A001', 'falar', 'verb', 'ter', 'verb', 'nada', 'pron', 'carro', 'sust', '', ''],
 ['A001', 'não', 'adv', 'perguntar', 'verb', 'problema', 'sust', 'carro', 'sust', '', ''],
 ['A001', 'não', 'adv', 'oferecer', 'verb', 'ligar', 'verb', 'compra', 'sust', '', ''],
 ['A001', 'não', 'adv', 'oferecer', 'verb', 'serviço', 'sust', 'compra', 'sust', '', '']]
```

And I want to remove empty elements from each list getting a new list of lists without the empty elements:

```
[['A001', 'atendimento', 'sust', 'concessionário', 'adv', 'bom', 'adj'],
 ['A001', 'falar', 'verb', 'ter', 'verb', 'nada', 'pron', 'carro', 'sust'],
 ['A001', 'não', 'adv', 'perguntar', 'verb', 'problema', 'sust', 'carro', 'sust'],
 ['A001', 'não', 'adv', 'oferecer', 'verb', 'ligar', 'verb', 'compra', 'sust'],
 ['A001', 'não', 'adv', 'oferecer', 'verb', 'serviço', 'sust', 'compra', 'sust']]
```

How could I achieve this?

I tried this:

```
str_list = filter(None, list_of_lists)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to remove empty lists from a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842956/python-how-to-remove-empty-lists-from-a-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your attempt will remove empty lists from the list of lists, not empty elements from the sublists. Instead, apply the filter to the sublists:

```
str_list = [list(filter(None, lst)) for lst in list_of_lists]
```

The call to `filter()` is wrapped with `list()` in case you happen to try this in python3 later, as `filter()` returns an iterator in py3.

Note that since you tagged this as [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) you might have to be careful as filtering might produce rows with differing lengths and items in wrong columns. If you know that for each row the 2 last items will always be empty, you could slice them out:

```
str_list = [row[:-2] for row in list_of_lists]
```

Comment: Note to OP: even in Python 3 the `list` call is optional depending on what you need to do. Iterators aren't evil, they just support less things like indexing.

Comment: Indeed, was just trying to keep the data closer to the original. Iterators really are handy, if you later have to go over the data just once.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `join`

```
output = [' '.join(i).split() for i in list_of_list]
```

Ouput

```
[['A001', 'atendimento', 'sust', 'concession\xc3\xa1rio', 'adv', 'bom', 'adj'],['A001', 'falar', 'verb', 'ter', 'verb', 'nada', 'pron', 'carro', 'sust'],['A001','n\xc3\xa3o','adv','perguntar','verb','problema','sust','carro','sust'],['A001','n\xc3\xa3o','adv','oferecer','verb','ligar','verb','compra','sust'],['A001','n\xc3\xa3o','adv','oferecer','verb','servi\xc3\xa7o','sust','compra','sust']]
```