# How do I move an empty array from a variable with multiple arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Variable with several arrays in it]

I got this after using this code:

> array1 = numpy.empty((0,4),int)
>
> for a,b,c,d in something:
>
> > array1 = numpy.vstack([array1,[a,b,c,d]])

I am not sure why I am getting empty arrays. Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842956/python-how-to-remove-empty-lists-from-a-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to remove empty lists from a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842956/python-how-to-remove-empty-lists-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [[], [1, 4]]
C = filter(lambda x: x!=[], L)
print(C)
```

**OUT:**

```
[[4,2]]
```

**ALTERNATIVE:**

```
C = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, L)
print(C)
```

**OUT:**

```
[[4,2]]
```