# Python - delete empty lists from a list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list that has several empty lists inside it. I followed the directions here ([Python: How to remove empty lists from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842956/python-how-to-remove-empty-lists-from-a-list)) in an attempt to filter out the empty lists but failed and I really have no reason why.

My list:

```
data: [['#0721', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['GBE COD', '746', '$2.00', '', '$1,492.00'], ['GBW COD', '13,894', '$0.50', '', '$6,947.00'], ['GOM COD', '60', '$2.00', '', '$120.00'], ['GB WINTER FLOUNDER', '94,158', '$0.25', '', '$23,539.50'], ['GOM WINTER FLOUNDER', '3,030', '$0.50', '', '$1,515.00'], ['GBE HADDOCK', '18,479', '$0.02', '', '$369.58'], ['GOM HADDOCK', '0', '$0.02', '', '$0.00'], ['GBW HADDOCK', '110,470', '$0.02', '', '$2,209.40'], ['HAKE', '259', '$1.30', '', '$336.70'], ['PLAICE', '3,738', '$0.40', '', '$1,495.20'], ['POLLOCK', '3,265', '$0.02', '', '$65.30'], ['WITCH FLOUNDER', '1,134', '$1.30', '', '$1,474.20'], ['SNE YT', '1,458', '$0.65', '', '$947.70'], ['GB YT', '4,499', '$0.70', '', '$3,149.30'], ['REDFISH', '841', '$0.02', '', '$16.82'], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['54 DAS @ $8.00/DAY = 432.00', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

My code:

```
data = filter(None, data)
print("second data:", data)
data = list(data)
print("third data:", data)
```

Which produces:

```
second data: <filter object at 0x05F23CF0>
third data: [['#0721', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['GBE COD', '746', '$2.00', '', '$1,492.00'], ['GBW COD', '13,894', '$0.50', '', '$6,947.00'], ['GOM COD', '60', '$2.00', '', '$120.00'], ['GB WINTER FLOUNDER', '94,158', '$0.25', '', '$23,539.50'], ['GOM WINTER FLOUNDER', '3,030', '$0.50', '', '$1,515.00'], ['GBE HADDOCK', '18,479', '$0.02', '', '$369.58'], ['GOM HADDOCK', '0', '$0.02', '', '$0.00'], ['GBW HADDOCK', '110,470', '$0.02', '', '$2,209.40'], ['HAKE', '259', '$1.30', '', '$336.70'], ['PLAICE', '3,738', '$0.40', '', '$1,495.20'], ['POLLOCK', '3,265', '$0.02', '', '$65.30'], ['WITCH FLOUNDER', '1,134', '$1.30', '', '$1,474.20'], ['SNE YT', '1,458', '$0.65', '', '$947.70'], ['GB YT', '4,499', '$0.70', '', '$3,149.30'], ['REDFISH', '841', '$0.02', '', '$16.82'], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['54 DAS @ $8.00/DAY = 432.00', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

So it didn't end up doing anything, why is that?

Comment: I don't see any empty lists here. A list with 5 empty strings in it still has 5 things in it.

Comment: Hi there. If you'd like to answer, please add it below - click on 'Answer Your Question'. We do not add solutions as edits to the question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `any(a_list)`, which is `True` if any element of `a_list` evaluates to `True`, as non-empty strings do.

```
data = [['#0721', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['GBE COD', '746', '$2.00', '', '$1,492.00'], ['GBW COD', '13,894', '$0.50', '', '$6,947.00'], ['GOM COD', '60', '$2.00', '', '$120.00'], ['GB WINTER FLOUNDER', '94,158', '$0.25', '', '$23,539.50'], ['GOM WINTER FLOUNDER', '3,030', '$0.50', '', '$1,515.00'], ['GBE HADDOCK', '18,479', '$0.02', '', '$369.58'], ['GOM HADDOCK', '0', '$0.02', '', '$0.00'], ['GBW HADDOCK', '110,470', '$0.02', '', '$2,209.40'], ['HAKE', '259', '$1.30', '', '$336.70'], ['PLAICE', '3,738', '$0.40', '', '$1,495.20'], ['POLLOCK', '3,265', '$0.02', '', '$65.30'], ['WITCH FLOUNDER', '1,134', '$1.30', '', '$1,474.20'], ['SNE YT', '1,458', '$0.65', '', '$947.70'], ['GB YT', '4,499', '$0.70', '', '$3,149.30'], ['REDFISH', '841', '$0.02', '', '$16.82'], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['54 DAS @ $8.00/DAY = 432.00', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]

non_empty = [sublist for sublist in data if any(sublist)]
print(non_empty)

[['#0721', '', '', '', ''],
 ['GBE COD', '746', '$2.00', '', '$1,492.00'],
 ['GBW COD', '13,894', '$0.50', '', '$6,947.00'],
 ['GOM COD', '60', '$2.00', '', '$120.00'],
 ['GB WINTER FLOUNDER', '94,158', '$0.25', '', '$23,539.50'],
 ['GOM WINTER FLOUNDER', '3,030', '$0.50', '', '$1,515.00'],
 ['GBE HADDOCK', '18,479', '$0.02', '', '$369.58'],
 ['GOM HADDOCK', '0', '$0.02', '', '$0.00'],
 ['GBW HADDOCK', '110,470', '$0.02', '', '$2,209.40'],
 ['HAKE', '259', '$1.30', '', '$336.70'],
 ['PLAICE', '3,738', '$0.40', '', '$1,495.20'],
 ['POLLOCK', '3,265', '$0.02', '', '$65.30'],
 ['WITCH FLOUNDER', '1,134', '$1.30', '', '$1,474.20'],
 ['SNE YT', '1,458', '$0.65', '', '$947.70'],
 ['GB YT', '4,499', '$0.70', '', '$3,149.30'],
 ['REDFISH', '841', '$0.02', '', '$16.82'],
 ['54 DAS @ $8.00/DAY = 432.00', '', '']]

￼
```

Comment: This is probably a dumb question but in your `non_empty` line, which of those are `1`'s (`one`) and which are `L`'s ?

Comment: @theprowler I changed the name.

Answer (score 0):

As user2357112 has pointed out you don't have empty lists, you have lists of the string '' whicch is not am empty list.

To solve your problem you should change the first parameter you are passing to filter.  filter(function, iterable) will return a list with values from iterable that functions returns true.

On your case, try:

```
def isEmpty(list):
    return any(list)

print filter(isEmpty, data)
```