# Matplotlib: multiple boxplot with (multiple) broken axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

First of all I show you what I need: I need a boxplot with broken x-axis, possibily more than a single break. An example is this figure
[image]

Now: I have two list of the form `X` and `Y` ( `X = float`, `Y = int`). First I group `Y` in sublists according to the integer part of `X` (`X` and `Y` are the same length):

```
number_of_units = int(max(X)) + 1
my_data = []
for i in range(number_of_units):
  my_data.append([])

for i in range(len(X)):
  j = int(X[i] )
  my_data[j].append(Y[i])
```

In this way `my_data` is a list of lists, with `number_of_units` sublists. The `k`-th subslist contains all the `X` values that are associated to `Y` values whose integer part is `k`. Here the problem: most of the subslists are empty: `Y` spans many orders of magnitude and typical values of `number_of_units` is `10^5`, but most of the `Y` have integer part in `[1,10]` so that most of the sublists in `my_data` are empty. The direct consequence is that if I do

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(my_data, 'options')
```

I obtain something like the following figure (note the "upper-right" red point):

[image]

This is due to the emptyness of most of the sublists in `my_data`: most of the plot shows "zero-frequency". So what I need is to break the x-axis of the plot whenever the frequency is zero. Note that:

- The points where the ax has to be broken must be found dynamically, since they change with the data.
- There are very high chances that the ax has to be broken multiple times

**Theoretical idea**

1. Split the list `my_data` into `M` lists of lists, where the split has to be done according to the emptyness of `my_data`: if `my_data[k]` is the first empty sublist, than `my_data[0],...,my_data[k-1]` is the first group; then find the first non empty sublist with index `>k` and there the second group begins. When I find another empty sublists, the second group is formed and so on. I hope I was clear.
2. Do a `ax.boxplot()` for each of the new list of lists. This time none of the sublists will be empty.
3. Plot each `ax` as subplots and join all the subplots as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185411/break-in-x-axis-of-matplotlib?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

This approach has a number of difficulties to me. The main problem is that I don't know *a priori* the number of subplots I will need, this number depending on the dataset and this is a problem I really don't know how to overcome. So I ask:

**How can I authomatically locate the regions of the X-axis that have non-zero frequency and plot only those regions, with an underlying broken ax everytime the regions end?**

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

My question is not a duplicate of [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319796/dynamically-add-create-subplots-in-matplotlib) because the latter does not contains any explanation on how to break the X axis. However the combination of the information in questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185411/break-in-x-axis-of-matplotlib?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319796/dynamically-add-create-subplots-in-matplotlib) might fully solve the problem. I'm actually working on it and I will edit the question further when the problem will be solved.

Comment: Have you tried to implement any of your proposed solutions (theories)? Which one did you like best and if it was not satisfactory, how was it deficient?

Comment: The theory is thought to be a unique solution: delete zero-frequency list, do the boxplots of non zero-frequency only and finally merge the various plots. I am not able to implement it because the number of subplots is not known a priori.

Comment: Are you asking how to go about making an unknown/arbitrary number of subplots?

Comment: I'am asking how to automatically plot only the regions of non zero frequency. If you kow how to do an unknown number of subplots, maybe I can go over my problem whit it. But it is not necessary, it is a possible solution.

Comment: `non zero frequency` means `sub-list in my_data that contain data`?  Are you asking two questions? How to filter out empty lists from `my_data` *and* how to make an arbitrary number of subplots from the result?

Comment: yes, this is the meaning of non zero frequency. I am not asking two questions. I don't know how to filter out empy lists but I can go over this (I hope). If you know how to do an arbitrary number of subplots maybe I can solve the problem. But if you know how to plot only the regions of non-zero frequency without filter out lists and doing many subplots it is fine too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically add/create subplots in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319796/dynamically-add-create-subplots-in-matplotlib).  It was hard to choose which was best suited for a dupe - search for `python matplotlib make an arbitrary number of subplots` maybe there is a better fit, but they all rely on looping through datasets and using them as arguments to `.subplot()`.  Seems you might also want to incorporate a shared y-axis feature.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because multiple subplots is not the only way to solve the problem. The question you posted may help me, but I don't need shared Y-axis for many subplots, I need a broken X-axis as in the link I posted at the point 3.

Comment: [Python: How to remove empty lists from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842956/python-how-to-remove-empty-lists-from-a-list) - you would be better off not putting them in there in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand: what you mean by "not putting them in there"? Putting who and where?

Comment: `my_data[j].append(Y[i])` -> use a conditional expression and only append them if they contain something.

Comment: Y[i] always contains something. The problem is the value of j: it can span from 0 to number_of_units, (e.g. 0, 1,...,10^5) but many of these values don't occurr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a data sample built like this:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from itertools import *
from operator import itemgetter
import scipy.stats as stats

def truncated_power_law(a, m):
x = np.arange(1, m+1, dtype='float')
pmf = 1/x**a
pmf /= pmf.sum()
return stats.rv_discrete(values=(range(1, m+1), pmf))

a, m = 2, 100000
d = truncated_power_law(a=a, m=m)
N = 10**2

X = np.sort(np.asarray(list(set(d.rvs(size=N)))))
Y = []
for i in range(0,len(X)):
Y.append(i*np.random.rand(100))
```

Don't care nothing about the data except that `X` is power law distributed. This imples that a lot of values between `min(X)` and `max(X)` don't appear in the sample.

Now, if you limit yourself doing

```
m_props = {'color': 'red',}
b_props = {'color': 'black', 'linestyle': '-'}
w_props = {'color': 'black', 'linestyle': '-'}
c_props = {'color': 'black', 'linestyle': '-'}

f_ugly, ax_ugly = plt.subplots()
ax_ugly.boxplot(Y, notch = 0, sym = '', positions = X, medianprops = 
        m_props, boxprops = b_props, whiskerprops = w_props, capprops 
        = c_props)
```

You obtain something like this:[image: bad_box]

Now consider this:

```
#X is divided in sublists of consecutive values
dominiums = []
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(X), lambda (i,j):i-j):
    dominiums.append(map(itemgetter(1), g))

number_of_subplots = len(dominiums)

k = 0
d = .01
l = .015

f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = number_of_subplots, sharex = 
              False, sharey = True, gridspec_kw = {'width_ratios':
              [3*len(dominiums[h]) for h in 
              range(number_of_subplots)],'wspace':0.05})

axes[0].yaxis.tick_left()
axes[0].spines['right'].set_visible(False)

kwargs = dict(transform = axes[0].transAxes, color='k', linewidth = 1, 
         clip_on = False)
axes[0].plot((1-d/1.5,1+d/1.5), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
axes[0].plot((1-d/1.5,1+d/1.5),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs)
kwargs.update(transform = axes[-1].transAxes)
axes[-1].plot((-l,+l), (1-d,1+d), **kwargs)
axes[-1].plot((-l,+l), (-d,+d), **kwargs)

for i in range(number_of_subplots):
    data_in_this_subplot = []
    for j in range(len(dominiums[i])):
        data_in_this_subplot.append([])
        data_in_this_subplot[j] = Y[k]
        k = k + 1

    axes[i].boxplot(data_in_this_subplot, notch = 0, sym = '', 
            positions = dominiums[i], medianprops = m_props, boxprops 
            = b_props, whiskerprops = w_props, capprops = c_props)

    if i != 0:
        axes[i].spines['left'].set_visible(False)
        axes[i].tick_params(axis = 'y', which = 'both', labelright = 
                False, length = 0)
    if i != number_of_subplots -1:
        axes[i].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        kwargs = dict(transform = axes[i].transAxes, color='k', 
                 linewidth = 1, clip_on=False)
        axes[i].plot((1-l,1+l), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
        axes[i].plot((1-l,1+l),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs)
        kwargs.update(transform = axes[i].transAxes)
        axes[i].plot((-l,+l), (1-d,1+d), **kwargs)
        axes[i].plot((-l,+l), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
```

Using the same data of the first figure, the latter code produces the following:
[image: good box]

IMHO this code fully answer to the question: it authomatically locate the relevant regions of the X axis and plot only those regions, whit an undelrlying broken ax everytime the region ends.

**Weankess of the solution**: it has a number of arbitrary parameters that must be tuned for every different data set (e.g. `d,l`, the number `3` in `3*len(dominiums[h]`)

**Strenght of the solution**: you don't need to know *a priori* the number of relevant regions (i.e. the number of subplots)

Thanks to wwii for his usefoul answer and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Without further evidence (your question lacks a minimal example of `X`and `Y`), 
it looks like `X` and `Y` values are *related* to each other by their positions/indices and you are trying to preserve that relationship by placing `Y` values *in* `my_data` at the index of the related `X` value.  I imagine you are doing that so you don't have to pass the `X` values to `.boxplot()` but that creates a lot of empty space that you don't want in your visualization.

If your data looks similar to this fake data:

```
X = [1,2,3,9,10,11,50,51,52]
Y = [590, 673, 49, 399, 551, 19, 618, 358, 106, 84,
     537, 865, 507, 862, 905, 335, 195, 250, 54, 497,
     224, 612, 4, 16, 423, 52, 222, 421, 562, 140, 324,
     599, 295, 836, 887, 222, 790, 860, 917, 100, 348,
     141, 221, 575, 48, 411, 0, 245, 635, 631, 349, 646]
```

The relationship between `X`, `Y`, and `my_data` can be seen by adding a print statement to the for loop that constructs `my_data`:

```
....
    my_data[j].append(Y[i])
    print(f'X[{i}]:{X[i]:<6}Y[{i}]:{Y[i]:<6}my_data[{j}:{my_data[j]}')  

>>>
X[0]:1     Y[0]:590   my_data[1:[590]
X[1]:2     Y[1]:673   my_data[2:[673]
X[2]:3     Y[2]:49    my_data[3:[49]
X[3]:9     Y[3]:399   my_data[9:[399]
X[4]:10    Y[4]:551   my_data[10:[551]
X[5]:11    Y[5]:19    my_data[11:[19]
X[6]:50    Y[6]:618   my_data[50:[618]
X[7]:51    Y[7]:358   my_data[51:[358]
X[8]:52    Y[8]:106   my_data[52:[106]

>>>
```

You would probably be better off not creating the empty space in the first place and just pass the x's and y's to `.plot` using `X` as the argument for `'plot`'s  `positions` parameter

```
# again fake Y data
y_s = [[thing] for thing in Y[:len(X)]]
plt.boxplot(y_s, positions=X)
```

This still leaves a lot of empty space in the plot. This can be *fixed* by segregating `X` and `Y` to slices of contiguous `X` values then creating subplots of the fragments using a loop (see [Dynamically add/create subplots in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12319796/2823755))