# python removing empty list inside a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

Ive tried a lot of combination how to remove this empty list from a dataframe, but it didnt work.

```
index_names = self.df[self.df['stopwords'].len()==0].index
self.df.drop(index_names, inplace=True)
```

dataframe called df['stopwords'] and it looks like this

[image: dataframe looks like this]

goal is to **delete the entire row of a dataframe** with [] list

Comment: `df = df.loc[df['stopwords'].ne([])]`?

Comment: does that equal to drop those empty list? @Ch3steR

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4842965/15095934) this should find all empty lists and delete them

Comment: [Find and delete all empty lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4842965/15095934)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `astype` with `bool`, since `[]` will return `False`

```
df = df[df['stopwords'].astype(bool)]
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

try if they are actual list object:

```
self.df.loc[~df['stopwords'].map(lambda x:not x)]
```

else if they are strings then use:

```
self.df.loc[df['stopwords'].ne('[]')]
```